# How to see text from one text field in another text field?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, c#-3.0

I have a tricky questian this time...for me anyway....

**clarify: i am using a virtual keyboard that has to work on deferent text fields, and deferent pages, every time i click on a text field it sould pop up and every key i press i need to show on the text field....the problem, as every one knows, is to bind a deferent text field to the virtual keyboard, And as i said, also, to use it on deferent pages without rewriting the keyboard code for every page again and again, some thing that will not do...
still can not give any code as there is no code to give, sorry.....looking for the algorithem...for the basic solution, so there is no code....sorry....**

Sorry i don't have code to show becouse i am trying to figure out how to do this and not showing a problem...

Background: I have an aspx file that holds a keyboard div and a hidden TextArea or an Input type=hidden (not decided yet). This page is a user control so it cen be used in all the pages that needs it...

What i am tring to do: Using JQuery bind('focus',...) method to bind any field in a certian aspx page (not the keyboard UC itself) to the hidden text field, i want that every thing i click on the keyboard will show in the text field that is on focus....

1. Can i relate in JS/JQuery to a field that is in a different page, will it recognise it?
2. how can i do the bind, how can i transfer text from one field to another?
3. if there a better way to do this, i will be happy to hear about it...

10x :-)

Comment: this doesnt make any sense. try re-wording you question to actually have a coherent question, and _do_ post some code because it will help people understand what you are trying to do. You say `"i want that every thing i click on the keyboard will show in the text field that is on focus"` thats how it works by default, the field with focus will collect what you type. what else do you mean? do you mean you want all text typed in any field to be appended to some single "log" field?

Comment: I think that's what he wants, but I agree with the whole 'coherent question' part. It would be very helpful to have a demo or at least a breakdown of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't use javascript across pages. It will only act on the currently active DOM.
2. example: $('input.field1').live('change', function() { $('input.field2').text( $(this).text() ) });
3. Please clarify your question, because it's not entirely clear what you want to achieve.